# How to write MYSQL queries in a DRY way

Tags: mysql, dry

I have a query like this, that looks at loads of different URLs, and groups them by hostname. It's pretty ugly, but seems fast enough to use.

How can I write it so that the ugly substring (which grabs the first part of the domain) is written in a neater way? I'm generating the query from an array of social media sites, so potentially there could be more sites there.

```
SELECT substring(r.name, 8, locate("/",substring(r.name FROM 8))-1) AS referer_domain,
       count(USER) AS hits,
       r.id
FROM core c,
     referer r
WHERE c.site_url = 12
    AND r.name LIKE '%/%'
    AND c.referer = r.id
    AND (substring(r.name, 8, locate("/",substring(r.name FROM 8))-1) = "www.delicious.com"
    OR substring(r.name, 8, locate("/",substring(r.name FROM 8))-1) = "www.facebook.com"
    OR substring(r.name, 8, locate("/",substring(r.name FROM 8))-1) = "m.facebook.com"
    OR substring(r.name, 8, locate("/",substring(r.name FROM 8))-1) = "www.reddit.com"
    OR substring(r.name, 8, locate("/",substring(r.name FROM 8))-1) = "twitter.com"
    OR substring(r.name, 8, locate("/",substring(r.name FROM 8))-1) = "news.ycombinator.com"
GROUP BY substring(r.name, 8, locate("/",substring(r.name FROM 8))-1)
ORDER BY hits DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you have already created an output column referer_domain which you can reference for the GROUP BY.

In order to use it in the WHERE clause, though you need a view.

```
CREATE VIEW ref_domain_view AS SELECT *,substring(name, 8, locate("/",substring(name FROM 8))-1) as referer_domain FROM referer;

SELECT r.referer_domain,
   count(USER) AS hits,
   r.id
FROM core c,
 ref_domain_view r
WHERE c.site_url = 12
AND r.name LIKE '%/%'
AND c.referer = r.id
AND referer_domain = "www.delicious.com"
OR referer_domain = "www.facebook.com"
OR referer_domain = "m.facebook.com"
OR referer_domain = "www.reddit.com"
OR referer_domain = "twitter.com"
OR referer_domain = "news.ycombinator.com"
GROUP BY referer_domain
ORDER BY hits DESC
```

Comment: This is what I started with, but it doesn't work, it says: Unknown column 'referer_domain' in 'where clause'

Comment: Nope. Didn't notice that! This doesn't quite work somehow. The view is correct, and has the right info in, but the query returns the number of rows in core for 5 of those domains, twice the number in core for one of them, and 2 for the other... It also takes around 6 seconds to run, rather than 80ms for the original query. Weird…

Comment: Hmm, it works on my test. I think you might have to fall back on a function as suggested in the other answers. Shame.

Comment: Weird. I'll have another go later this week, this feels so close, yet so far :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to write a [user-defined function (UDF)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-function-udf.html) that does the string extraction.  UDF's are fast, but more of a pain to write.  Another alternative is to write a [stored function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/create-procedure.html) a type of stored procedure which is simpler to write and more in line with SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

While the above two answers have very good points I have to ask you something.

Do you really need all the substring function calls?

Have you tried something like this:

```
SELECT substring(r.name, 8, locate("/",substring(r.name FROM 8))-1) AS referer_domain,
   count(USER) AS hits,
   r.id
FROM core c,
 referer r
WHERE c.site_url = 12
AND r.name LIKE '%/%'
AND c.referer = r.id
AND r.name    = "http://www.delicious.com"
OR r.name     = "http://www.facebook.com"
OR r.name     = "http://m.facebook.com"
OR r.name     = "http://www.reddit.com"
OR r.name     = "http://twitter.com"
OR r.name     = "http://news.ycombinator.com"
GROUP BY substring(r.name, 8, locate("/",substring(r.name FROM 8))-1)
ORDER BY hits DESC
```

The only problem with the above query would be if you needed more domains to track you would need to alter the query. If you put the domains into a table and joined to that table you could probably get rid of the substring completely and also never have to alter the query.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. The actual urls in referer_domains are the full URL, something like http://www.facebook.com/l.php?ajasdjasldjaoiwurwruw98fy0asdfyasdkfbsdetcetec. I have considered trimming them and having the domain and the page in seperate fields, but that's not what I've been doing so far.